# What type of tenants' rights does a student renting from privately-independently owned student halls have?

Tags: tenant, scotland, students

Suppose a private student housing company maintains student halls for students to book into and live in, but they only accept bookings from university students, though they will accept  students from any university and are not  specifically associated with any one university in particular. Suppose that Alice, a student at the university of Leeds, decides to rent an accommodation from them. What type of tenancy would she have and what statutory terms and protections to it would apply?

Answer (score 2):

They have a common law tenancy. Generally, in most cases where they don't live with a landlord, this means that a court order will be required to evict them.